# EFCore: Query a related entity based on the maximum value in a field in the related entity

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, ef-core-2.2

I need to query a related entity based on the maximum value in a field in the related entity, and then display results from that item.

For example, the models are defined:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ICollection<ReportCard> ReportCards {get; set;}
}

public class ReportCard
{
    public int ReportCardID {get; set;}
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public int Result {get; set;}
    public int Comment {get; set;}
    public DateTime PublishDate {get; set;}
}
```

In the razor controller:

```
public class LatestResultsModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    public IList<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        Students = await _context.Student
                                 .Include(student => student.ReportCard)
                                 .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

In the razor view:

```
@foreach (Student student in Model.Students)
{
    <p>@student.Name</p>
    <p>@student.ReportCard.Max(i => i.PublishDate).Result.ToString()</p>
}
```

After the Max statement I cannot query the other fields.
I've tried a few things to achieve this outcome of filtering the related data.

[Filtered Includes are not supported.](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/1833)

Is there some type of join that could achieve this outcome?

It also doesn't handle the situation when a Student has no ReportCard. InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After the Max statement I cannot query the other fields. I've tried a few things to achieve this outcome of filtering the related data.

Yes! You cannot! because `Max` statement select only the field that you mention in the `Max`.

> It also doesn't handle the situation when a Student has no ReportCard. InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

Do as follows to overcome both problems:

```
@foreach (Student student in Model.Students)
{
    <p>@student.Name</p>

    if(student.ReportCards.Count > 0)
    {
      <p>@student.ReportCards.OrderByDescending(rc => rc.PublishDate).FirstOrDefault().Result.ToString()</p>

      <p>@student.ReportCards.OrderByDescending(rc => rc.PublishDate).FirstOrDefault().PublishDate.ToString()</p>
    }
    else
    {
      <p>Student has no report card!</p>
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!